# Making the Background Image of a UIView on Aspect Fit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a sort of drawing app using objective-c, and for one of my `UIView`s, I want there to be a background image to it. However, I want this background image on the actual `UIView`, not a separate `UIImageView`. I did that using this:

```
self.tempDrawImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
```

In this code, tempDrawImage is a UIImageView I made programmatically, and after initializing it, I wrote this later in the code so that the drawings would appear on top of the image. I don't know if this is helpful, but I thought I'd include it anyway just in case it does help.

```
- (UIImageView *)tempDrawImage
{
    if(!_tempDrawImage) _tempDrawImage = [UIImageView new];
    return _tempDrawImage;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Now, I'm struggling to make the image that I set to image.jpg in the beginning aspect fit. How could I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImageView image distorts when big image is placed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653413/uiimageview-image-distorts-when-big-image-is-placed)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
self.tempDrawImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

```
 self.tempDrawImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```